# How do I choose my static IP address/Gateway etc?

Tags: networking, static-ip

How do I choose my:

1. address
2. netmask (255.255.255.0?)
3. network
4. broadcast
5. gateway

The tutorials and commentary from many of the more experienced penguins seems to assume that people have their level of understanding when it comes to this sort of thing.

Do I just pick any set of random numbers? This is not explained very well by anyone. The only constant across all of the tutorials is that netmask always seems to be 255.255.255.0.

All I want is my wired connection to work and I don't understand why ubuntu didnt automatically detect it when installing.

Comment: What are you connecting to? What's on the other end of the connection?

Comment: Just a switch connected to a router. Actually its a switch connected to another switch connected to a router

Comment: Given it's that weird a network setup, you should ask whoever is administering your network what the expected network configuration is.

Comment: Im the only person here lol I have a lot of miners going. Man I thought mining was hard ubuntu is just ridiculous

Comment: If your ethernet won’t connect automatically, then a static IP is unlikely to help. I suggest that you tell us the details of the ethernet chip. lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3

Answer (score 0):

255.255.255.0 is a standard class C network, giving 254 addresses to the local network. It is standard the router is at one end or the other - 1 or 254 - giving xxx.xxx.xxx.1 or xxx.xxx.xxx.254.

The router may be set to give addresses dynamically, as devices connect (DHCP) or you may need to set all addresses manually if DHCP is switched off. It's usual to have a pool of DHCP e.g. 50-253 which would allow 2-49 to be static addresses.

192.168.1.1 - router
192.168.1.2 - static address of PC
...
192.168.1.50 - DHCP address for phone on WiFi

You need to start by identifying the IP of the router and knowing if DHCP is switched on (+what addresses are in the DHCP pool) so you can work out what addresses can be static.

Comment: On a windows machine I did cmd then ipconfig/all and found my default gateway to be 10.0.0.1 which I have been led to believe is my routers ip address? I would imagine it is set to DHCP since every other device has had no such problem, I don;t know how to check if it's on or off. I guess Ill look into that.

Comment: Apparently my DHCP server address is 10.0.0.1 as well. Not sure if that helps Thanks for the help btw

Comment: So if 10.0.0.1 is my router address, would I set my computers address to 10.0.0.2? What if I have switches? Would they have an address too? If so would that mean I should assume every switch between my router and pc would have an address and to take them into account accordingly?

Comment: Using CMD > ipconfig /all it should show your subnet mask too. If it's 255.255.255.0 or /24 then that would work. Can you access your routers config web page at http://10.0.0.1

Comment: Are the other devices attached to the same *switch* in the range of 10.0.0.x?

Comment: My subnet mask is 255.255.255.0            I don't know how to access my routers config webpage        and nothing is wireless everything has a lan connection             also could someone tell me how to start a new paragraph on these forums every time I hit enter to move down a line it just flippin posts my comment

Comment: Ok so If what I'm reading is correct All I have to do to access my routers webpage is to type 10.0.0.1 into a serach bar and hit enter? Ok here goes

Comment: It brought me to an xfinity page telling me to enter my login to mess with my router

Comment: I will add to my first comment down here that Yes I have tried multiple ethernet cables on the trouble computer, the ethernet cable worked for windows and it was only when I installed 14.04 that it magically stopped working.   Thanks again for your help

Comment: What address does a device get if you connect?